# how to subtract the next column by the previous column and create a new column after?

Tags: r

There are here on stackoverflow questions about how to diff a column by the previous column like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49552469/subtract-one-column-from-previous-column) my question is a little bit different, i want to create a new column after that diff and don't modify the existing columns

Sample data:

```
dfData <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                  DistA = c(10, 8, 15, 22, 15), 
                 DistB = c(15, 35, 40, 33, 20),
                 DistC = c(20,40,50,45,30),
                 DistD = c(60,55,55,48,50))

   ID DistA DistB DistC DistD
 1  1    10    15    20    60
 2  2     8    35    40    55
 3  3    15    40    50    55
 4  4    22    33    45    48
 5  5    15    20    30    50
```

Expected output:

```
   ID DistA DistB DiffB-A  DistC DistD  Diff D-C
 1  1    10    15   05      20    60    40
 2  2     8    35   27      40    55    15
 3  3    15    40   25      50    55    05
 4  4    22    33   11      45    48    03
 5  5    15    20    5      30    50    20
```

Subtract the next column by the previous column and create a new column after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to subtract every two columns,  we can use `split.default` to split the data into two columns each and subtract the second column with the first one.

```
cols <- ceiling(seq_along(dfData[-1])/2)
new_cols <- tapply(names(dfData[-1]), cols, function(x) 
                   sprintf('diff_%s', paste0(x, collapse = '')))
dfData[new_cols] <- sapply(split.default(dfData[-1], cols), function(x) 
                     x[[2]] - x[[1]])
dfData

#  ID DistA DistB DistC DistD diff_DistADistB diff_DistCDistD
#1  1    10    15    20    60               5              40
#2  2     8    35    40    55              27              15
#3  3    15    40    50    55              25               5
#4  4    22    33    45    48              11               3
#5  5    15    20    30    50               5              20
```

Comment: and how to insert the new_cols in the dfData by every two columns of dfData?

Comment: I see that you have asked a new question with this and found a solution.